# How to get a Firestore document size?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

From [Firestore docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas), we get that the **maximum size for a Firestore document** is:

> Maximum size for a document **1 MiB** (1,048,576 bytes)

**QUESTION**

How can I know the current size of a single doc, to check if I'm approaching 
that 1mb limit?

**Example:**

```
var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");

docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
        // IS THERE A PROPERTY THAT CAN DISPLAY THE DOCUMENT FILE SIZE?
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The calculations used to compute the size of a document is fully documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size).  There is a lot of text there, so please navigate there to read it.  It's not worthwhile to copy all that text here.

If you're having to manually compute the size of a document as it grows, my opinion is that you're probably not modeling your data scalably.  If you have lists of data that can grow unbounded, you probably shouldn't be using a list field, and instead put that data in documents in a new collection or subcollection.  There are some exceptions to this rule, but generally speaking, you should not have to worry about computing the size of a document in your client code.

Comment: Any plans on releasing the code for these estimations? It would be a good thing for the community to get hold of.

Comment: There are cases where having such data would be extremely useful. For example in the case of a chat application with a lot of exchanges the messages could be  batched into fewer documents to improve read performance, up to a safe value. Current load times of a chat history in Angular for a chat app loading individual responses from Firestore leave much to be desired.

Comment: This is a doulble edged sowrd, where we have to choose between worrying about the growing document size versus the growing number of docments.
Adding data to one document will save retrieval time and cost (reading one document cost), but we have to worry about the docuement size.
While splitting the data over multiple document will help avoid the document size limit, but it will increase the retrieval time and cost (reading multiple documents cost).

IMO, there should be an attribute in the document metadata for the document size.

Comment: @MAW This is a real scenario in my opinion too. The hosting costs can sprial out with a large number of documents that all need to be fetched, but have a small amount of data in them. It's not like adding a row in database table. Knowing the size can help optimise Firestore usage.

Answer (score 19):

I've published a npm [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firestore-size) that calculates the size of a Firestore document.

Other packages like `sizeof` or `object-sizeof` that calculate the size of JS object will not give you a precise result because some primitives in Firestore have different byte value. For example boolean in Js is stored in 4 bytes, in a Firestore document it's 1 byte. Null is 0 bytes, in Firestore it's 1 byte.

Additionally to that Firestore has own unique types with fixed byte size: Geo point, Date, Reference.

Reference is a large object. Packages like `sizeof` will traverse through all the methods/properties of Reference, instead just doing the right thing here. Which is to sum String value of a document name + path to it + 16 bytes. Also, if Reference points to a parent doc , `sizeof` or `object-sizeof` will not detect circular reference here which might spell even bigger trouble than incorrect size.

Answer (score 8):

Nowadays, there is [Firestore Document Size Extension](https://extensions.dev/extensions/alexmamo/firestore-document-size) that can help you calculate the size of the document.

**How it works?**

Each time a new document is added at a specific location in Firestore, a Cloud Function will fire and it will calculate the size of the document according to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size). The size, which is actually the number of bytes, is written at a specific location in the Realtime Database. So if you're d dealing with heavy objects, it's best to check the size of the document against the maximum 1 MiB limitation before adding more data.

---

<strike>For Android users who want to check the size of a document against the maximum of `1 MiB` (1,048,576 bytes) quota, there is a library I have made that can help you calculate that:</strike>

- https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreDocument-Android/tree/master/firestore-document

In this way, you'll be able to always stay below the limit. The algorithm behind this library is the one that is explained in the official documentation regarding the [Storage Size](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size).

Comment: Its very simple and useful.

Comment: @Pooja Yes, it really is.

Comment: Is there any way I can use this inside Unity?

Comment: @Jay I'm not sure if you can use this library inside Unity. Never tried that.

Answer (score 6):

I was looking in the Firebase reference expecting the metadata would have an attribute, but it doesn't. You can check it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#metadata).

So my next approach would be to figure the weight of the object as an approximation. The [sizeOf library](https://github.com/lyroyce/sizeof) seems to have a reasonable API for it.

So it would be something like:

```
sizeof.sizeof(doc.data());
```

I wouldn't use the document snapshot, because it contains metadata, like if there are pending saves. On another hand overestimating could be better in some cases.

[UPDATE] Thanks to Doug Stevenson for the wonderful insight

So I was curious **how much the difference would actually be**, so with my clunky js I made a dirty comparison, you can see the [demo here](https://327239.playcode.io/)

Considering this object:

```
 {
  "boolean": true,
  "number": 1,
  "text": "example"
  }
```

And discounting the `id` this is the result:

```
| Method  | Bytes |
|---------|-------|
| FireDoc | 37    |
| sizeOf  | 64    |
```

So sizeOf library could be a good predictor if we want to overestimate (assuming calculations are fine and will behave more or less equal for more complex entities). But as explained in the comment, it is a **rough estimation**.

Comment: Yeah. I was expecting that too. But didn't find anything.

Comment: I would not trust that sizeof library to be an accurate representation of the size of a Firestore document.  The size of a JS object in memory is going to be different than the size of a document persisted in Firestore.  The implementation of a JS object could vary drastically between various runtimes.  I would only use that library as a very rough estimate.  I would expect the estimate to be more accurate in the case of large string values, and less accurate when there are lots of fields of various non-basic types.

Comment: @DougStevenson updated answer, it was fun, hope to help

Answer (score 2):

For Swift users,

If you want to estimate the document size then I use the following.  Returns the estimated size of document in Bytes.  It's not 100% accurate but gives a solid estimate.  Basically just converts each key, value in the data map to a string and returns total bytes of String + 1.  You can see the following link for details on how Firebase determines doc size: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size.

```
func getDocumentSize(data: [String : Any]) -> Int{
        
        var size = 0
        
        for (k, v) in  data {
            
            size += k.count + 1
            
            if let map = v as? [String : Any]{
                size += getDocumentSize(data: map)
            } else if let array = v as? [String]{
                for a in array {
                    size += a.count + 1
                }
            } else if let s = v as? String{
                size += s.count + 1
            }
    
        }
        
        return size
        
    }
```

Comment: Firebase also includes "32 additional bytes" per document plus the size of the document name (about 30 by default), so add ~60 to whatever this total of this func is.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this calculator (code snipped), i write by myself.

source : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Calculte Firestore Size</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Firestore Document Size Calculator</h1>
    <h2 id="response" style="color:red">This is a Heading</h2>
    <textarea id="id" style="width: 100%" placeholder="Firestore Doc Ref"></textarea>
    <textarea id="json" style="width: 100%; min-height: 200px" placeholder="Firestore Doc Value JSON STRING"></textarea>
    <textarea id="quantity" style="width: 100%;" placeholder="How Many repeat this value?"></textarea>
    <script>
     document.getElementById("json").value='{"type": "Personal","done": false , "priority": 1 , "description": "Learn Cloud Firestore"}'
     document.getElementById("id").value = 'users/jeff/tasks/my_task_id'
     calculate()
     function yuzdeBul(total,number) {
        if (number == 0) {
          return 0;
        }
        const sonuc = Math.ceil(parseInt(number) / (parseInt(total) / 100));
        return sonuc;
      }
      function calculate(){
        var quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById("quantity").value || 1);
        var firestoreId = document.getElementById("id").value;
        var refTotal = firestoreId
            .split("/")
            .map((v) => v.length + 1)
            .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) + 16;
        var idTotal = 0
          
        //console.log(idTotal);
        var parseJson = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("json").value);
        idTotal += calculateObj(parseJson);
        idTotal+=32;
        idTotal*=quantity; 
        idTotal+=refTotal;
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = idTotal + "/" + 1048576 + " %"+yuzdeBul(1048576,idTotal);
      }
      function calculateObj(myObj) {
        var total = Object.keys(myObj).map((key) => {
          var keySize = key.toString().length + 1;
          var findType = typeof myObj[key];
          //console.log(key,findType)
          if (findType == "string") {
            keySize += myObj[key].length + 1;
          } else if (findType == "boolean") {
            keySize += 1;
          }
          if (findType == "number") {
            keySize += 8;
          }
          if (findType == "object") {
            keySize += calculateObj(myObj[key]);
          }
          return keySize;
        });
        return total.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
      }
      document.getElementById("json").addEventListener("change", calculate);
      document.getElementById("id").addEventListener("change", calculate);
      document.getElementById("quantity").addEventListener("change", calculate);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30150609)

Answer (score 2):

So I was looking for a way to reduce unnecessary document reads by accumulating data in arrays and go worried about the size.

Turns out I wasn't even close to the limit.

Here's what you can do,
Create a new collection and add a document with the worst-case scenario for live data and using cloud console export that collection, you will see the document size.

[Here is a screenshot of my export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r59c0.png)

Assuming all the documents are equal in size, each is 0.0003MB

You can also see if the documents exceed the 1024byte limit
[document exceeding limit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGina.png) from the console

Note: you can only export when you have enabled billing.!