# How to save very long string into firebase firestore database?

Tags: json, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to insert very long string to firebase firestore
and I receive this error message

```
Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(Error performing setData,
INVALID_ARGUMENT: The value of property "json" is longer than 1048487 bytes., null))
```

my code is :

```
  Future<void> addREportToDB(String addedCount, String deletCount, String updatedCount, String json) {
        // Map decodedCloud = jsonDecode(json);
    return Firestore.instance.collection("reports").add({
      "dateCreate": new DateTime.now(),
      "addedCount": addedCount,
      "deletCount": deletCount,
      "updatedCount": updatedCount,
      "json": json,
      // "json":decodedCloud,
    }).then((doc) {
      print(doc.documentID.toString());
    });
  }
```

and the (***json***)variable This is a text I get from another API and this text contains the data of more than 600 employees in the form of JSON string
and all I need to save this as it

any help will be appreciated

Comment: If you are getting json data, why not break it down into independent json style documents. Perhaps even put each element into an array. Shouldn't be too much of an issue to iterate over 600 elements and do something separate with them instead of just storing them all in one node (field).

Answer (score 3):

There is no way you can add into a single document data above that limitation. So there are some limits when it comes to how much data you can put into a single document. According to the official documentation regarding [usage and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas):

> Maximum size for a document: 1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes)

As you can see, you are limited to 1 MiB total of data in a single document. You can use alternative solution for storing larger amounts of data. You should try using [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage).

Comment: Well, if 1 char == 8 bits, it is limited to around 1 million characters, or?

Comment: @PavelPoley It depends on the size of the keys and the values you store in them. There's a [library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56330030/how-to-get-a-firestore-document-size) that can help you check the size of a document against the maximum of 1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes) quota.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum size of a document in Cloud Firestore is 1MB. If you want to store more data, consider either splitting it over more documents or (more likely in this case) storing it in Cloud Storage (for which a Flutter SDK also exists).

Answer (score 0):

Just save them separately to firestore and when you want to use them in your app, you can use string operation to join the two seperate strings you saved to make it the original long string