# How to sort firebase documents by the size of a list in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Could someone explain to me how I can order documents on Firebase by the size of a list?

I have this 'rec' list on several items, but I can only sort it as:

```
body: FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              future: Firestore.instance
                  .collection("products")
                  .document(snapshot.documentID)
                  .collection("items")
                  .orderBy("rec")
                  .getDocuments(),
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yV9D.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a **recSize** key to your documents and a firebase function that recalculates the size of your list every time the list changes. Then order using recSize.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore does not provide us with metadata, hence in order to get the size of a document stored in a collection you can proceed with one of the following:

- As Henok pointed out, use a field to store the current size of the document and use it to sort your data on the back-end side.
- Download your unsorted documents and sort them on the client according to their size.

Please check out this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56330030/how-to-get-a-firestore-document-size) which you may found useful in both cases.