# what is Cloud Firestore Stored Data quota?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, quota

I'm on the free Firebase plan, with not too many users.

Most of the resources I use make sense (Read Operations, Write Operations etc.) - I understand the daily usage, the the daily quotas.

What puzzles me is the "**Cloud Firestore Stored Data**" quota:

1. The usage there makes no sense to me (1.17 of 1 GB) - there's no possible way that my users create 1GB of documents each day
2. It doesn't get **reset** each day (although it's supposed to be daily)
3. I did notice it can get higher and **lower** over time (went from 96% to 70% and then to 100%), so I don't think it's a cumulative quota

Tried to look for some explanation for this resource and couldn't find any...

Since this is the only resource that pushes my free plan limit, I'd love to know more about it, and if and how I can control/reduce it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) says that on its free plan Cloud Firestore has:

> Stored data: 1 GiB total

This is the total storage that is allowed, not a periodic allotment. So unlikely bandwidth, and read/write quota, this one doesn't get reset every day/month.

Comment: Indeed the pricing page says that, but on the GCP console that number is under "Usage today" column, which can be misleading... Also: I'm quite sure that saw this number goes down from 96% to 70%, without deleting any documents...
But your answer makes sense, Frank, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to have more details about your indexes and data I believe can only be seen from your [Firebase Console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/monitor-usage#firebase-console).

To calculate the size of the documents by following [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size#document-size) link and it will help you to understand calculations. I would recommend you to verify [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56330030/how-to-get-a-firestore-document-size) other stackoverflow post discusses about how to get a Firestore document size.

Another option you have to monitor the information your users write per day, is using [Stackdriver Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/monitor-usage#cloud-monitoring). Also note that using Stackdriver Monitoring you can also get metrics on Document Reads, and Document Deletes.

In case you notice something strange on that information, I would recommend you to open a case support in order to take a look at it.

Comment: I estimate my documents to be 1K-10K each, where ~500 new documents are create each day, which brings us to ~5M total / day. So I don't see how the "Cloud Firestore Stored Data" can be >1G, unless it is a cumulative quote... But then again, if it's cumulative quote, how comes it dropped down from 96% to 70% the other day?